# Installing dependencies in pypy virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv, pypy

I am trying to install my python package inside virtual environment with pypy interpreter. I'm working on CentOS 7 and I did the following:

1) Create virtualenv with pypy:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/pypy pypy-env
```

2) Activate it using:

```
source pypy-env/bin/activate
```

3) Try to install my package using:

```
pip install .
```

The last command fails with following error:

```
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... error
Complete output from command /network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-iiZlol/matplotlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-57lig2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include/site/python2.7/matplotlib:
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [2.1.0]
                python: yes [2.7.10
                        (bbd45126bc691f669c4ebdfbd74456cd274c6b92, Jun 30
                        2016, 15:15:02) [PyPy 5.0.1 with GCC 4.8.5 20150623
                        (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]]
              platform: yes [linux2]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.10.0]
                   six: yes [using six version 1.11.0]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.6.1]
backports.functools_lru_cache: yes [using backports.functools_lru_cache]
/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/site-packages/subprocess32.py:472: RuntimeWarning: The _posixsubprocess module is not being used. Child process reliability may suffer if your program uses threads.
  "program uses threads.", RuntimeWarning)
          subprocess32: yes [using subprocess32]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2017.3]
                cycler: yes [using cycler version 0.10.0]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [using pyparsing version 2.2.0]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: yes [version 2.4.11]
                   png: yes [version 1.5.13]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'libqhull' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]
        toolkits_tests: no  [skipping due to configuration]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PySide2 not found; PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: no  [Microsoft Windows only]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: yes [version 1.14]
           ghostscript: yes [version 9.07]
                 latex: yes [version 3.1415926]
               pdftops: yes [version 0.26.5]

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

running install
running build
running build_py
copying lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/mpl-data
UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/_version.py
set build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/matplotlib/_version.py to '2.1.0'
running build_ext
building 'matplotlib.ft2font' extension
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src
cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include -I/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include -c src/ft2font.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -I/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include -I/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I. -I/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include -c src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/ft2font_wrapper.o
cc1plus: warning: command line option ‘-Wimplicit’ is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++ [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:26:0,
                 from src/file_compat.h:7,
                 from src/ft2font_wrapper.cpp:3:
/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h: In function ‘int _import_array()’:
/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1651:13: error: ‘NPY_CPU_UNKNOWN_ENDIAN’ was not declared in this scope
   if (st == NPY_CPU_UNKNOWN_ENDIAN) {
             ^
/usr/include/numpy/__multiarray_api.h:1662:13: error: ‘NPY_CPU_LITTLE’ was not declared in this scope
   if (st != NPY_CPU_LITTLE) {
             ^
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Command "/network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/bin/pypy -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-iiZlol/matplotlib/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-57lig2-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /network-raid/opt/python/virtualenvs/pypy-env/include/site/python2.7/matplotlib" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-iiZlol/matplotlib/
```

I was positioned in directory containing setup.py for my package. The contents of my setup.py file are:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

"""
My package setup script.
"""

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='viz_tools',
      version='1.0',
      setup_requires=[
          'numpy'
      ],
      install_requires=[
          'docopt',
          'matplotlib',
          'numpy',
          'scipy',
          'seaborn',
          'sklearn'
      ],
      py_modules=[
          'common',
          'datamanip',
          'drawing'
      ],
      scripts=[
          'convert_old_data',
          'convert_old_iteration_data_to_json',
          'generate_heatmap',
          'generate_histograms',
          'generate_iteration_json',
          'generate_min_max_bar'
      ])
```

I managed to do this with python (2.7.10) but it doesn't seem to work with pypy. The command:

```
pypy --version
```

produces the follwing output:

```
Python 2.7.10 (bbd45126bc691f669c4ebdfbd74456cd274c6b92, Jun 30 2016,15:15:02)
[PyPy 5.0.1 with GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-4)]
```

Comment: `pypy` is a very special beast regarding binary extensions. Are you sure all your dependencies listed in `install_requires` work with `pypy`?

Comment: ``error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1`` --- this means that the compiler failed, and gave errors just above.  What are these errors?

Comment: I updated the log with full command output.